# How to associate rows based on key and previous key without multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in a table that looks like:

| ID | previous_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | NULL |  |
| 02 | 01 |  |
| 03 | 02 |  |
| 04 | 03 |  |
| .. | .. |  |

I would like to set the value for the row based on the value of the row with the previous Id equal to this rows ID. For example, if row with ID = 04 has a value of 1, I would like the row with the previous ID = 04 to also have the value of 1, which in turn would cause the row with the previous ID = 03 to have a value of 1 and so forth.

I have no set number of connected rows, and the IDs are GUIDs.

Is there a way to perform such a function without the use of temporary tables, where it would check the value of the row with previous ID equal to the rows ID and then assign a value based on that rows value in the same column.

pseudo SQL for the recursive logic I am imagining:
case when not exists (row with previous ID equal to ID) then randomColumn else value of row with previous id end as value

Comment: It sounds like the `LAG` analytic function may be what you're after, or maybe `FIRST_VALUE` or `LAST_VALUE` depending. Please edit your question to include the actual data along with the expected output. Where does the value of `1` that you talk about come from, for example?

Comment: PL/SQL is the programming language. Queries are SQL. Updated question and tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results you directly requested using a single simple JOIN:

```
select c.id, c.prev_id, p.val 
 from tbl c
 left join tbl p 
   on (c.prev_id = p.id) 
order by c.id;
```

Lead/Lag functions fail because they depend upon sequencing, There is nothing to guarantee that sequencing in your data as *the IDs are GUIDs*.

However that leaves much still to be answered. You have established a hierarchical relationship, so does the result need to reflect that relationship? With a single branch and with the id:prev_id being nicely ordered, that basically needs no additional work. But hierarchies seldom maintain so an order - they tend to get messy. To unravel it you need a to specifically address the  hierarchy itself. The best way to accomplish that (in Oracle) is with  [start with ... connect by ...](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_GQMLEEPG5ARVSIFGQRD3SES92.html) (See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8cc436c7dbfa9676864227d858df0408). Has both)

```
select id
     , prev_id
     , (select val 
          from tbl t
         where t.id = h.prev_id
       ) 
  from (select id, prev_id
          from tbl 
        connect by prev_id = prior id 
          start with prev_id is null 
        ) h;
```